# Embed CouchDB on OS X app (zero deployment)

Tags: macos, couchdb

I'm looking for a way of embedding a CouchDB instance on an OSX app so the user doesn't have to install anything. Is this possible?

I've looked into CouchDBX but it seems it's completely abandon, and couldn't find a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking at TouchDB as a suitable option
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-iOS

This allow you to build it inside the app and the user will not have to do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think that's iOS only. Altough they have a hack "CocoaHTTPServer" to make it run on the Desktop they say it's still not stable and that should not be used :(

Comment: I understand well then why not embed sqlite? virtually all apple successful apps for iPad and desktop use sqlite. It would be for sure lighter and faster too ?

Comment: Well I was looking specifically for CouchDB to get the auto magic replication/sync functionality for free :)

Comment: TouchDB works for OS X, BUT it is not CouchDB. It lacks a lot of features that CouchDB has for handling large quantities of data. TouchDB is meant for clients accessing CouchDB servers or lite P2P systems, not for acting as a full fledged server.